# Копирование одного массива в начало другого

Tags: c#

Нужно скопировать массив Data2 в начало массива Data без потери начальных данных в Data. Пробую вот таким кодом:

```
byte[] Data //Первый массив
byte[] Data2 //Первый массив
Array.Resize(ref Data, Data.Length + Data2.Length);
Array.Copy(Data2, 0, Data, 0, Data2.Length);
```

Но на выходе получаю данные из Data2 и нули, все байты из Data не "сдвинулись" вперед а пропали.

Comment: А вы ж копируете куда? В начало? А в начале у вас что? Чужие данные? Вот и перетираете.

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно что вы хотите видеть в "голове", что в "хвосте". Вам нужно или Copy - переместить данные в "хвост" у Data, либо Data2 писать не в 0, а в Data.Length который до изменения длинны массива  (или он же теперь после resize равен `Data2.Length - Data.length` вместо 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ничего не потеряете, если вместо расширения массива просто создадите новый, поэтому рекомендую воспользоваться операцией Linq [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Data = Data2.Concat(Data).ToArray();
```

На самом деле `Array.Resize` поступает примерно так же - создает новый массив и копирует в него элементы из старого, после чего старый просто подбирается сборщиком мусора.